# Contents inside the DIV are being Overlapped when the window opened as window.open

Tags: css

Please see the Image here  http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=56eb165

When the Page is opened as Window.open , the contents are being overlapped as shwon in the Picture .

As you can see from the Image that the Hyper Link Print is being overlapped .

This is the code i am using

```
     <div style="background-color:#99CCFF;white-space: nowrap;">
<hr><p><div style="float: right;"><a href="url">Print</a></div><span STYLE="font-size:24; font-weight:bold; color: black">Site:</span> Downtown Denver DataCenter - CCODEN44 | <span STYLE="font-size:24; font-weight:bold; color: black">Device:</span> CCODEN44-ACME-RTR-1 | <span STYLE="font-size:24; font-weight:bold; color: black">Interface:</span> Wilmington DataCenter, DC  <hr></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personally would have wrote this a little better but here is what I adjusted.

-Wrapped your text inside a p tag
-added a hr tag with a clear:both to clear the floated anchor tag

```
<div style="background-color:#99CCFF;white-space: nowrap;overflow:hidden">

  <div style="float: right"><a href="url">Print</a></div>

  <hr/ style="clear:both">

  <p> <span STYLE="font-size:24; font-weight:bold; color: black">Site:</span> Downtown Denver DataCenter - CCODEN44 | <span STYLE="font-size:24; font-weight:bold; color: black">Device:</span> CCODEN44-ACME-RTR-1 | <span STYLE="font-size:24; font-weight:bold; color: black">Interface:</span> Wilmington DataCenter, DC</p>

  <hr/>
</div>
```